# Combining CSV's into one master CSV

Tags: csv, csvkit

Im currently playing with [CSVKIT](http://csvkit.readthedocs.io/en/0.9.1/index.html) to try and combine a few csv into one master, I can get it to do two (I don't mind doing this manually for each one). But my issue runs into the following;

- I wanted to preserve data that matches in columns and preserves the
  "ID, StockNumberID" column.
- Add not found column to the end of the row.
- The primary column "StockNumberID" in this case needs to be the primary key.

I've been running this command and playing with flags but so far not found much luck.

`csvjoin -c "StockNumberID,StockNumberID" -e utf-8 -d, -S --outer 1.csv 2.csv`

**Im open to different solutions**, I've played with applications that "promise" these features but no success.

Answer (score 1):

Check out this tool - it's based off of csvkit but has a ton of additional features. One of our engineers custom built it - and open sourced it to help solve some of these data issues we deal with every day :)

https://github.com/DataFoxCo/gocsv